# jQuery - Not Selector in Body

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i've got a site with the usual syntax (header, main, footer).
I got a subnavigation in my main section.

My Problem:
The subnavigation has the id #nav_sub. If the pages "imprint", "contact" or "newsletter" has been loaded, my CMS (Contao) is adding the class "footerstyle" in the body-tag, looking like this:

```
<body class="mac chrome ch24 footerstyle">
```

For the subnavigation I'm adding a nice hover effect BUT I don't want this effect on the subnavigation when "footerstyle" is loaded. Is this somehow possible?

This is how I select the subnavigation:

```
var $subnavi = jQuery("#nav_sub #navigation");
```

I tried :not and .not() but It hasn't worked.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing your existing selector `"#nav_sub #navigation"` is correct (the element with id `navigation` if it's inside an element with id `nav_sub`), then you might use

```
$("#nav_sub #navigation").not("body.footerstyle #navigation")
```

or

```
$("body:not(.footerstyle) #nav_sub #navigation")
```

If you don't have special condition about #navigation being in #nav_sub, simply use

```
$("body:not(.footerstyle) #navigation")
```

Comment: The second (and probably the first too) selector did it! Thank you very much!